# Add additional select attributes to grouped product's child collection

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, grouped-products

I am trying to add additional attributes to the collection that is created when getting a grouped product's associated simple products:

```
# Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped

public function getAssociatedProducts($product)
{
    if (!$product->hasData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts)) {
        $associatedProducts = [];

        $this->setSaleableStatus($product);

        $collection = $this->getAssociatedProductCollection(
            $product
        )->addAttributeToSelect(
            ['name', 'price',  'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date']
        )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
            $this->getStoreFilter($product)
        )->addAttributeToFilter(
            'status',
            ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
        );

        foreach ($collection as $item) {
            $associatedProducts[] = $item;
        }

        $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);
    }
    return $product->getData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts);
}
```

The attributes I would like to add are image-related ('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail').

I put together a plugin that will redo the collection, but I'm getting an error that I'm passing the wrong type:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Vendor\\Swatches\\Plugin\\GroupedSwatches::afterGetAssociatedProducts() must be an instance of Magento\\Catalog\\Model\\Product, instance of Magento\\GroupedProduct\\Model\\Product\\Type\\Grouped\\Interceptor given
```

Here is my (very inefficient) plugin method:

```
public function afterGetAssociatedProducts(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $result)
{
    $associatedProducts = array();
    $collection = $product->getAssociatedProductCollection(
        $product
    )->addAttributeToSelect(
        ['name', 'price', 'special_price', 'special_from_date', 'special_to_date', 'image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail']
    )->addFilterByRequiredOptions()->setPositionOrder()->addStoreFilter(
        $this->getStoreFilter($product)
    )->addAttributeToFilter(
        'status',
        ['in' => $this->getStatusFilters($product)]
    );

    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $associatedProducts[] = $item;
    }

    $product->setData($this->_keyAssociatedProducts, $associatedProducts);

    return $result;
}
```

Is this even the right approach for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For adding additional attributes for child in grouped product, add code like this to a `Plugin/Model/Product/Type/GroupedPlugin.php` file in your extension (this example assumes your extension is `VendorName_ModuleName`)

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Model\Product\Type;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection;
use \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped as Grouped;


class Grouped
{
    public function afterGetAssociatedProductCollection(Grouped $subject, Collection $result)
    {
        $result->addAttributeToSelect('attr1');
        $result->addAttributeToSelect('attr2');

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And add this code to an `etc/frontend/di.xml` file in your module:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped">
        <plugin sortOrder="1" name="moduleNamePluginGrouped" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Model\Product\Type\GroupedPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Hello! would you be able to lookup or remember what you used in di.xml for this plugin? I'm trying to make it work for me but as soon as I enable the plugin I get blank where the attribute information should be on the page, with no error. Similar to what https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232332/magento-2-plugin-not-extending-model-finally-solved-it they solved it by duplicating some of the Grouped core code but there must be a better way? I suspect the type name= in di is where I am going wrong

Comment: Hi Erik 
I've returned to this one again - it works. Though I had an odd collision of Grouped so changed the function line to public function afterGetAssociatedProductCollection(\Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped $subject, Collection $result)

Comment: add attribute to select works with arrays. If you do it this way it seems as though you are making a separate query each time.