# Magento 2 Plugin Not Extending Model - Finally Solved It

Tags: custom-attributes, grouped-products, magento2.2.4, after-plugin

I'm trying to use a plugin from the answer on this question

[Add additional select attributes to grouped product's child collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166428/add-additional-select-attributes-to-grouped-products-child-collection)

I would go back and ask the person who answered but I don't have a high enough reputation score yet to add comments.

I don't use composer, so have gone the old route of app/code.

My plugin looks like this

```
<?php
namespace mynamespace\Plugingrouped\Plugin;
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection;
use \Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped as TypeGrouped;
class Grouped
{
public function afterGetAssociatedProductCollection(TypeGrouped $subject, Collection $result)
{
$result->addAttributeToSelect('my_attribute_weight');
$result->addAttributeToSelect('my_attribute_height');
return $result;
}
}
?>
```

I've added the plugin code as Grouped.php into a folder
app/code/mynamespace/Plugingrouped/Plugin

My di.xml file in my module looks like this

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type">
    <plugin name="Grouped" type="Mynamespace\Plugingrouped\Plugin\Grouped" />
</type>
```

And then I tried calling a custom attribute in

app/design/frontend/Mynamespace/base/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.html

```
<strong class="product-item-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></strong>
                Weight : <?php echo $_item->getmy_attribute_height() ?>
```

To add custom attributes into the grouped product grid.

However, they don't render, I don't get an error, but I can't figure out how to make sure the plugin is working.

Comment: Use Namespace instead of namespace in your plugin file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

Assuming you meant 

Namespace mynamespace\Plugingrouped\Plugin;

Unfortunately that didn't work either.

It renders everything around the custom attribute but nothing from the attribute itself

Comment: @SukumarGorai Though it is technically possible to use sentence case for some PHP operators, it is best practice to lowercase them, therefore the OP was correct to use the lowercase version of the operator `namespace`.

Comment: @ProcessEight - Thanks for the update. I've put it back to lowercase but no luck on it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many many days of banging my head on a wall, I've finally solved it.

I had two modules set up originally:

1. Mynamespace\Grouped\
2. Mynamespace\Plugingrouped

Nothing I did would make the plugin show up until I combined the two into module.

I now have the Model override and plugin in one module and it's working.

In case anyone else is having the same nightmare:

My di.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped" type="Mynamespace\Grouped\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Grouped" />
        <type name="Mynamespace\Grouped\Model\Rewrite\Product\Type\Grouped">
        <plugin name="Mynamespace_grouped_groupedproduct_model" type="Mynamespace\Grouped\Plugin\Grouped" />
        </type>
</config>
```

Folder Structure looks like:

```
Mynamespace
  ->Grouped
    ->etc (di.xml & module.xml)
    ->Model->Rewrite->Product->Type->Grouped.php (copy of core)
    ->Plugin->Grouped.php (containing plugin code)
```

On the frontend I've added the attributes into overriden copy of

app/design/frontend/Mynamespace/base/Magento_GroupedProduct/templates/product/view/type/grouped.html

and hey presto it worked.

A big thank you to those who replied and tried to help and I hope this answers helps others.

Now all I need to do is get them to show up in the cart and throughout checkout

:-)

Comment: Hi. Are you saying you had to add a copy of part of the Grouped model with your plugin for it to work, without any changes? I'm having a similar problem and was hoping i just needed to get the details right in my di.xml :S

Answer (score 0):

Please try below

```
<type name="Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped">
    <plugin name="Grouped" type="Mynamespace\Plugingrouped\Plugin\Grouped" />
</type>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that didn't work either.

It's driving my around the bend, I've spent days on it.

It just doesn't return the value in the attribute

:-(

Comment: I think you set 'Yes' in Used in Product Listing for this attribute.

Comment: Yes they are set to "Yes"


They show up on the simple product pages but I can't add them to a group grid