# Override function from grouped.php

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, overrides, xml, grouped-products

I am changing the table for a grouped product.
I have overridden the grouped.phtml file to make changes.

But I need to override the function:

```
getAssociatedProducts($product) // Grouped.php
```

Because some attributes are not available. Only a few are added by

```
->addAttrubuteToSelect(...) // Grouped.php
```

I need more attributes to be visible in the table.

Files can be found in:

Magento\GroupedProduct\Model\Product\Type\Grouped.php (where to override?)

and

module-grouped-product\view\frontend\templates\product\view\type\grouped.phtml (overridden in custom theme)

Or do I need to override a XML file to store the new attribute? Which one?

Comment: This one works for me: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/166428/add-additional-select-attributes-to-grouped-products-child-collection

Answer (score 0):

You also have have access to the `getAssociatedProductsCollection($product)` method, why not use that?